# Running headless Chromium Browser throws error 'Failed to read DnsConfig' (inside Docker container)

Tags: angular, docker, karma-jasmine, chromium

**My Goal:**
To run unit tests on my Angular 6 app (that runs inside of a Docker container) using Karma/Jasmine. In order to run these tests it appears I need a web browser. So it seemed like Chromium headless was a good option. I've gotten it installed along with a bunch of other libraries through my Dockerfile, but running my tests inside of the Docker container fails (running tests outside of it works fine).

**The Error:**

```
23 02 2019 04:28:08.884:ERROR [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless stdout: 
23 02 2019 04:28:08.884:ERROR [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless stderr: [0223/042808.557529:WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(326)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
[0223/042808.591436:FATAL:udev_loader.cc(38)] Check failed: false.
```

Actually opening up a browser (http://localhost:9876/) and then running tests will still cause the headless to fail, but the tests to show up in the browser. Nice to see the tests, but not too helpful if I want these unit tests to eventually run as a part of CI or something.

My guess is that I may not actually need the DNS working (it does say WARNING from the stderr output), but I'm not sure how to go about disabling it.

**Here's the current browser configuration in the Karma test runner:**

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCustom'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCustom: {
    base: 'ChromiumHeadless',
    flags: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--allow-insecure-localhost',
      '--homepage=about:blank',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--headless',
      '--disable-software-rasterizer',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-translate',
      '--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9876'
    ]
  }
}
```

The only significant flags would be the `headless` and `no-sandbox` flags, everything else I've thrown in while browsing other posts and hasn't appeared to have any effect.

**The Dockerfile (where I think I install Chromium succesfully):**

```
FROM node:8-alpine

# Install Google Chrome to run Angular unit tests
ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
ENV LIGHTHOUSE_CHROMIUM_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser

RUN \
  echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && apk --no-cache  update \
  && apk --no-cache  upgrade \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gifsicle pngquant optipng libjpeg-turbo-utils udev ttf-opensans chromium
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/* /usr/include
```

So if anybody has any suggestions on where to go from here, or if I've missed some other obvious simple way of running these tests, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fail to localize the problem. But as I found out, instang packets like in [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/blob/master/Dockerfile) produces working image, without this error.

This fixes the problem, while not reveals its cause.